# Exception in SQL server 'Incorrect syntax near '.'. '?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Create Proc Proc_Name
as begin
  SELECT 1111 AS sno,'--ALL--' AS RS.branch
  UNION 
  SELECT Rs.Sno,(RS.branch+'-'+RT.[Type] ) AS branch 
  FROM K_RT_MasterRetailStores Rs 
  INNER JOIN K_RT_RetailType RT ON RT.sno=RS.[Type] 
  ORDER BY Rs.Branch 
end
```

I am getting Incorrect syntax error near '.'. in SQL server. I am not able to find out my mistake. Please guide me.

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure K_RT_GetRetailBranch, Line 16
Incorrect syntax near '.'.   Its not working getting same exeception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Create Proc Proc_Name
as
begin 
    select *
    from
    (select 1111 as sno,'--ALL--' as branch
    union 
    select Rs.Sno, RS.branch + '-' + RT.[Type]
    from K_RT_MasterRetailStores Rs 
    inner join K_RT_RetailType RT on RT.sno = RS.[Type])
    order by Branch 
end
```

Comment: I don't think `order by Rs.Branch` will work. The `order by` sorts the complete union result, not just one part of the union. And the result of the union does not have a column named `RS.Branch` only one that is called `Branch`

Answer (score 2):

Remove the table name from the alias

```
select 1111 as sno, '--ALL--' as  branch
                                 ^--------------here
```